# Run jQuery.BlackAndWhite on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

jQuery.BlackAndWhite creates an SVG and desaturates it on hover.  The plugin works fine when I hover the image.  But I have images inside a container.  I need to extend the "hot area" of the hover to the entire div instead of only the image.  I'm not sure if its possible with this plugin.

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="bw">
        <img src="myimage.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.item').hover(function(){

  $(this).find('.bw').BlackAndWhite({
      hoverEffect : true, // default true
      webworkerPath : false,
      invertHoverEffect: true,
      intensity:1,
      speed: { 
          fadeIn: 200, // 200ms for fadeIn animations
          fadeOut: 300 // 800ms for fadeOut animations
      },
      onImageReady:function(img) {
      }
  });

});
```

I would create a JSFiddle but this plugin needs a local image to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the plugin, look for these lines...

```
    // binding the hover effect
    if (hoverEffect) {

        $container.on('mouseleave', _onMouseLeave);
        $container.on('mouseenter', _onMouseEnter);
    }
```

You'll want to change that so it's targeting the parent of your specified container, in your case, it's only one child level deep so you would modify the above to target that like so

```
    // binding the hover effect
    if (hoverEffect) {

        $container.parent().on('mouseleave', _onMouseLeave);
        $container.parent().on('mouseenter', _onMouseEnter);
    }
```